# Magento 2 save admin id to database using plugin

Tags: magento2.3.4

**I am getting errors in save method.**

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Codilar\OrderComment\Model\Api\OrderCommentUserRepository::save() must
> be an instance of Codilar\OrderComment\Model\OrderCommentUser,
> instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\History\Interceptor
> given, called in
> /var/www/html/lal-magento/app/code/Codilar/OrderComment/Plugin/Sales/Model/Order.php
> on line 56 and defined in
> /var/www/html/lal-magento/app/code/Codilar/OrderComment/Model/Api/OrderCommentUserRepository.php:56
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/lal-magento/app/code/Codilar/OrderComment/Plugin/Sales/Model/Order.php(56):
> Codilar\OrderComment\Model\Api\OrderCommentUserRepository->save() #1

**di.xml** code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\History">
        <plugin name="AddAdminNameToComment" type="Codilar\OrderComment\Plugin\Sales\Model\Order" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
    <preference for="Codilar\OrderComment\Api\OrderCommentUserRepositoryInterface" type="Codilar\OrderComment\Model\Api\OrderCommentUserRepository"/>
</config>
```

**Plugin\Sales\Model\order.php** code is

```
<?php
namespace Codilar\OrderComment\Plugin\Sales\Model;

use Codilar\OrderComment\Api\OrderCommentUserRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderStatusHistoryInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session;

/**
 * Class Order
 * @package Codilar\OrderComment\Plugin\Sales\Model
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session
     */
    protected $authSession;
    /**
     * @var OrderStatusHistoryInterface
     */
    private $orderStatusHistory;
    /**
     * @var OrderCommentUserRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderCommentUserRepository;

    /**
     * Order constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
     * @param OrderStatusHistoryInterface $orderStatusHistory
     * @param OrderCommentUserRepositoryInterface $orderCommentUserRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        Session $authSession,
        OrderStatusHistoryInterface $orderStatusHistory,
        OrderCommentUserRepositoryInterface $orderCommentUserRepository
    ){
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->orderStatusHistory = $orderStatusHistory;
        $this->orderCommentUserRepository = $orderCommentUserRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $subject
     * @param $comment
     * @param $status
     * @param $isVisibleOnFront
     */
    public function afterSave(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\History $subject, $result)
    {

        $adminId = $this->authSession->getUser()->getId();
        $model = $this->orderCommentUserRepository->create();
        $model->setData([
            'admin_id' => $adminId
        ]);
        $this->orderCommentUserRepository->save($model);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rk Rathod i am facing the error can you please help me.

Comment: Share the Complete code on that file.

Comment: where i am not understanding

Comment: this file path : Plugin\Sales\Model\order.php